# Bootstrap Tooltip works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I have a button such as:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id={{name}} name="logoutUserButton" data-toggle="logoutUserConfirmation"  {{disableLogout}}><em class="fa fa-lg fa-sign-out" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout User"></em></button>
```

Notice that I had to use two data-toggles. On the click of the button, I get a confirm box to confirm the action. Now, When I hover the mouse over the icon, I get the tooltip that says "logout user"

All this works perfectly fine in chrome. However, the tooltip fails to work in Firefox. I'm able to get the tooltip workign for a  element but not for a  or  or  element. 
Although not required, I've tried initializing the tooltip, but it still does not show.

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip']).tooltip()
```

What are some workarounds for this?

Comment: Any error firefox-console?
Run this in firefox console. $('[data-toggle=tooltip']).tooltip() 
If not works, try jquery no conflict

Comment: @blacmoon - I get this: ```Object { length: 13, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → listUserProfiles, selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]", 13 more… }``` but still don't see the tooltip. I need to mention that the tooltip shows up on the <button> element even without intitializing. But somehow when nesting it inside the button tag, it fails to show up.